# Unable to connect to Orion Context Broker using Wirecloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I am new to FIWARE. I managed to install Orion Context Broker on my local system following the steps mentioned in the FIWARE website. I am able to use CURL commands to create entities and also retrieve values.

I have also installed Wirecloud on my local system and able to access Wirecloud UI from my browser.

But I am unable to display the entities on the Wirecloud widgets.  I have tried all widgets including "NGSI Type Browser", NGSI Browser and NGSI Source operator.

All returning the same error: "ConnectionError: Unexpected response from WireCloud's proxy"

Please help me on how to proceed.  My NGSI-proxy is also running and listening on port 3000.  Screenshots attached.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4sWD.png)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to replace `localhost` with `IP address` of your machine running Orion and Ngsiproxy?